# Method (step) get a NotImplementedError in file A but in file B not

Tags: python-behave

I implemented step:

```
@given('my step')
def step_impl(context):
    somthing
```

In file fileA.py this method (step) get a NotImplementedError but if i moved this method to another file eg. fileB.py step is running properly.

I don't know why and how can i fix it

Answer (score 0):

You provide not enough information to answer your question. 
Provide the StackTrace or look at the StackTrace when you get the NotImplementedError.

HINT: 
Could be a weird Unicode encoding problem in "fileA.py" 
(Unicode has also invisible characters)